# Is MySQL stored procedure transactional by default?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a MySQL stored procedure which reads and updates multiple tables, so I want it to be a transaction. Is it already transactional by default? Or do i need to do something?

MySQL 5.0+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe so. According to the [manual section on `BEGIN...END` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html):

> Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events), the parser treats BEGIN [WORK] as the beginning of a BEGIN ... END block. Begin a transaction in this context with START TRANSACTION instead.

Also see the manual on [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html).